# error receiving JSON is badly formatted or it contains invalid character php curl

Tags: php, json, php-curl

JSON is badly formatted or it contains invalid character, tried few suggestions but still receiving same error please help on this following is my json posting using curl

complete curl request

```
    $url='https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v2/quickteller/payments/transfers';
     $postdata='{
            "mac":"9F4E4F53C57BE63E1F08D8F07A7BC1A9461E4A7D5304043DAA1EF54BD727B6CDE148F4FBFC5E2AD8C4A60F78DFA76304DE671FBEB70657B1628F14B6B6BAA5E1",
            "beneficiary":{
                "firstname":"chi",
                "lastname":"chi",
                "othernames":"chi"
                },
            "initiatingEntityCode":"FIB",
            "initiation":{
                "amount":"100000",
                "channel":"7",
                "currencyCode":"566",
                "paymentMethodCode":"CA"
            },
            "sender":{
                "email":"isw@interswitch.com",
                "lastname":"Phil colins",
                "othernames":"Phil colins",
                "phone":"08124888436"
            },
            "termination":{
                "accountReceivable":{
                    "accountNumber":"0012000887",
                    "accountType":"10"
                },
                "amount":"100000",
                "countryCode":"NG",
                "currencyCode":"566",
                "entityCode":"058",
                "paymentMethodCode":"AC"
            },
            "transferCode":"1016858652542545"
     }';

    $data=json_encode(json_decode($postdata));       
    $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    ));                                                                                                                  


    $result = curl_exec($ch); 



    echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';

    var_dump($result);
```

but still receiving the error
JSON is badly formatted or it contains invalid character.

Comment: Json syntax seems to be correct (tested with https://jsonlint.com). Is there any "semantical error", that the receiving server can not read? Can you show php code of curl request?

Comment: Yes, I tried it too. and it works fine

Comment: What you are actually trying with this Json string?

If you are create this Json string on your own remove it to avoid such error.. Instead of creating your own Json string, you first create array with the values then you use json_encode() to create Json sting.

Comment: Where are you getting the error and what is the exact problem?

Comment: @BenRoob question updated

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea how the interswitch api works. Maybe you can refer to documentation and check, if for example "amount" or "channel" must be post as string value? It really seems like the api cannot handle this incoming json.

Comment: https://confluence.interswitch.com/confluence/display/QPR/Funds+Transfer

check this

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is valid.

You can do

```
print_r(json_decode($postdata));
```

It will convert it to an object.

If you just want to remove the formatting, and have a one line string:

```
echo json_encode(json_decode($postdata));
// output:
// {"mac":"9F4E4F53C57BE63E1F08D8F07A7BC1A9461E4A7D5304043DAA1EF54BD727B6CDE148F4FBFC5E2AD8C4A60F78DFA76304DE671FBEB70657B1628F14B6B6BAA5E1","beneficiary":{"firstname":"chi","lastname":"chi","othernames":"chi"},"initiatingEntityCode":"FIB","initiation":{"amount":"100000","channel":"7","currencyCode":"566","paymentMethodCode":"CA"},"sender":{"email":"isw@interswitch.com","lastname":"Phil colins","othernames":"Phil colins","phone":"08124888436"},"termination":{"accountReceivable":{"accountNumber":"0012000887","accountType":"10"},"amount":"100000","countryCode":"NG","currencyCode":"566","entityCode":"058","paymentMethodCode":"AC"},"transferCode":"1016858652542545"}
```

Comment: i tried but still having same issue , question updated please check

Comment: then it's not a JSON error, it's an API error. For some reason, it doesn't like this input. Do you have any documentation on how to interact with the API? Are any fields missing or have incorrect values?

Comment: https://confluence.interswitch.com/confluence/display/QPR/Funds+Transfer
check this URL a method which is i am trying to implement